# Cannot resolve dependency to assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2013, infragistics

I'm getting this error message when I compile my solution:

> Unknown build error, 'Cannot resolve dependency to assembly 'InfragisticsWPF.Controls.Charts.XamDataChart, Version=15.1.20151.1000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb' because it has not been preloaded. When using the ReflectionOnly APIs, dependent assemblies must be pre-loaded or loaded on demand through the ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve event. Line 11 Position 10.'

So far I've tried unsuccessfully the following solutions:

- [Unknown build error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840753/unknown-build-error)
- [Unkown build error usign WPF toolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447657/unknown-build-error-using-wpf-toolkit)
- [Errors when referencing Silverlight class library from WPF

  application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232646/errors-when-referencing-silverlight-class-library-from-wpf-application)

Any pointers?

Comment: Have you seen this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/3405483/2461203

Comment: Perhaps this might help you more ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405053/visual-studio-build-problem-with-reflectiononlyassemblyresolve-event

Comment: @3-14159265358979323846264 that's a link to the question of the answer to which I linked..

Comment: @ragerory Great minds think alike. Clearly your fingers are quicker though :0)

Comment: @ragerory. Yes I have seen it. But it is not my case.

Comment: @3-14159265358979323846264 Thanks to you too.

Comment: I had the same error (using VS 2013) for a class library with a decorator class, to register itself as a ClassHandler for ClickEvent. It uses reflection to invoke the the base class OnClick method so that a click on a child fires the command and the click event on the parent. It builds without error using VS 2017 RC and if just click "Yes" on the the dialog asking to continue with the last successful build, it works fine, including new changes. It's a ReSharper bug I think. Then I realised I could do the same thing with IsHitTestVisible and it was moot.

Answer (score 1):

That assembly name just does not look right for the latest Infragistics control version 15.1. A couple of things I would try:

1. Run the latest Infragistics Version Utility to upgrade the project, if you have not already.
2. In your Solution Explorer, delete the reference to "InfragisticsWPF.Controls.Charts.XamDataChart" and add it back in, but the reference should look something like: "Infragistics**WPF4**.Controls.Charts.XamDataChart" (the number 4 being the .Net version your project is set up for)
3. Delete the chart control and delete the reference, and from your Toolbox, drag the control back into your window and the correct reference(s) will be added for you.

Comment: I'm using the signed and version free of the InfragisticsWPF.Controls.Charts.XamDataChart assembly. Although I will try deleting the reference and recreating it.

Answer (score 1):

InfragisticsWPF.Controls.Charts.XamDataChart should be either in GAC or accessible through HintPath. Obviously it's not in GAC.

Check if your .csproj contains correct Reference with HintPath set and your DLL is exactly there. Should be something like this:

```
<Reference Include="InfragisticsWPF.Controls.Charts.XamDataChart">
    <HintPath>..\My\Assembly\Path\InfragisticsWPF.Controls.Charts.XamDataChart.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

If it's there than check version.